# Hibernate 6.1.x stitching schema and name are incorrect

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I upgraded Spring Boot 2.7.x to Spring Boot 3.0.x. The corresponding Hibernate is also upgraded from `5.1.x` to `6.1.x`.

My Oracle database table is:

```
SELECT * FROM CUST_CENTER.PROD_INST@HUIJK;
```

The corresponding Java Entity definition is:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "CUST_CENTER", name = "PROD_INST@HUIJK")
public class 产品实例实体 {
    @Id
    private Long prodInstId;
    // ...
}
```

This was working fine before the upgrade, but after the upgrade I get errors like this:

```
2023-04-03 18:48:10 DEBUG [http-nio-4159-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(at line 128)   : select 产1_0.prod_inst_id,产1_0.acc_num,产1_0.acc_prod_inst_id,产1_0.accept_type_cod,产1_0.account,产1_0.acct_id,产1_0.act_date,产1_0.action_id,产1_0.address_desc,产1_0.address_id,产1_0.area_code,产1_0.basic_state,产1_0.begin_rent_date,产1_0.besp_date,产1_0.besp_symbol,产1_0.bill_date,产1_0.bill_xchg_id,产1_0.busi_mod_date,产1_0.common_region_id,产1_0.create_date,产1_0.create_org_id,产1_0.create_staff,产1_0.cust_id,产1_0.cust_order_id,产1_0.data_aoc_type,产1_0.dev_efp_date,产1_0.dev_exp_date,产1_0.develop_department,产1_0.developer,产1_0.distributor_id,产1_0.eff_date,产1_0.exch_id,产1_0.exp_date,产1_0.ext2_prod_inst_id,产1_0.ext_prod_inst_id,产1_0.ext_state,产1_0.first_finish_date,产1_0.grp_prod_nbr,产1_0.handler,产1_0.handler_latn_id,产1_0.if_ivpn,产1_0.install_addr,产1_0.install_date,产1_0.ip_flag,产1_0.ismp_aoc_type,产1_0.lan_id,产1_0.last_order_id,产1_0.last_order_item_id,产1_0.latn_id,产1_0.lte_flag,产1_0.offer_id,产1_0.owestate_date,产1_0.owner_cust_id,产1_0.pay_cust_id,产1_0.pay_latn_id,产1_0.payment_mode_cd,产1_0.physical_nbr,产1_0.point_owner_id,产1_0.prod_id,产1_0.prod_inst_desc,产1_0.prod_inst_name,产1_0.prod_inst_pwd,产1_0.prod_type_cd,产1_0.prod_use_type,产1_0.region_id,产1_0.remark,产1_0.sms_aoc_type,产1_0.status_cd,产1_0.status_date,产1_0.stop_rent_date,产1_0.update_date,产1_0.update_staff,产1_0.urban_flag,产1_0.urge_cd,产1_0.use_cust_id,产1_0.use_latn_id,产1_0.user_bill_id,产1_0.user_type_id,产1_0.voice_aoc_type from cust_center."prod_inst@huijk" 产1_0 where 产1_0.acc_num=? and 产1_0.status_cd not in(?,?,?)
2023-04-03 18:48:10  WARN [http-nio-4159-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(at line 133)  : SQL Error: 942, SQLState: 42000
2023-04-03 18:48:10 ERROR [http-nio-4159-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(at line 138)  : ORA-00942: 表或视图不存在

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select 产1_0.prod_inst_id,产1_0.acc_num,产1_0.acc_prod_inst_id,产1_0.accept_type_cod,产1_0.account,产1_0.acct_id,产1_0.act_date,产1_0.action_id,产1_0.address_desc,产1_0.address_id,产1_0.area_code,产1_0.basic_state,产1_0.begin_rent_date,产1_0.besp_date,产1_0.besp_symbol,产1_0.bill_date,产1_0.bill_xchg_id,产1_0.busi_mod_date,产1_0.common_region_id,产1_0.create_date,产1_0.create_org_id,产1_0.create_staff,产1_0.cust_id,产1_0.cust_order_id,产1_0.data_aoc_type,产1_0.dev_efp_date,产1_0.dev_exp_date,产1_0.develop_department,产1_0.developer,产1_0.distributor_id,产1_0.eff_date,产1_0.exch_id,产1_0.exp_date,产1_0.ext2_prod_inst_id,产1_0.ext_prod_inst_id,产1_0.ext_state,产1_0.first_finish_date,产1_0.grp_prod_nbr,产1_0.handler,产1_0.handler_latn_id,产1_0.if_ivpn,产1_0.install_addr,产1_0.install_date,产1_0.ip_flag,产1_0.ismp_aoc_type,产1_0.lan_id,产1_0.last_order_id,产1_0.last_order_item_id,产1_0.latn_id,产1_0.lte_flag,产1_0.offer_id,产1_0.owestate_date,产1_0.owner_cust_id,产1_0.pay_cust_id,产1_0.pay_latn_id,产1_0.payment_mode_cd,产1_0.physical_nbr,产1_0.point_owner_id,产1_0.prod_id,产1_0.prod_inst_desc,产1_0.prod_inst_name,产1_0.prod_inst_pwd,产1_0.prod_type_cd,产1_0.prod_use_type,产1_0.region_id,产1_0.remark,产1_0.sms_aoc_type,产1_0.status_cd,产1_0.status_date,产1_0.stop_rent_date,产1_0.update_date,产1_0.update_staff,产1_0.urban_flag,产1_0.urge_cd,产1_0.use_cust_id,产1_0.use_latn_id,产1_0.user_bill_id,产1_0.user_type_id,产1_0.voice_aoc_type from cust_center."prod_inst@huijk" 产1_0 where 产1_0.acc_num=? and 产1_0.status_cd not in(?,?,?)]; SQL [n/a]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:256)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:232)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy244.findByAccNumAndStatusCdNotIn(Unknown Source)
```

I manually executed the SQL statement `select 产1_0.prod_inst_id,产1_0.voice_aoc_type from cust_center."prod_inst@huijk" 产1_0` generated by Hibernate and got the same error, but the execution(`select 产1_0.prod_inst_id,产1_0.voice_aoc_type from cust_center.prod_inst@huijk 产1_0`) was normal after removing the quotation marks.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### temporary solution:

Let me share my temporary solution first:

```
// I created custom implementation PhysicalNamingStrategy class
package com.example;

import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;

public class MyPhysicalNamingStrategy extends CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier logicalName, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        // Here, I will always set the quoted property to false
        return new Identifier(super.toPhysicalTableName(logicalName, jdbcEnvironment).getText(), false);
    }

}
```

Then add a line `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy: com.example.MyPhysicalNamingStrategy` to `application.yaml` to tell Hibernate to use custom classes for physical naming.

Note: This solution is only recommended as a temporary solution, when special characters really appear in the project, Hibernate's quote escape feature will fail (because we reimplemented the physical table naming and always set the quote to false)

---

### some other infomations:

- [Hibernate 6.0 Migration Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#id-sequence-table-name)
- personal guess: I compared the SQL statements generated by Hibernate `5.x` and `6.x`. The SQL statements generated by `5.x` do not have double quotes by default (that is, the table name part is `from cust_center.prod_inst@huijk`), while `6.x` by default, the generated SQL statement uses double quotation marks to enclose the table name (that is, the table name part is `from cust_center."prod_inst@huijk"`), and the latter cannot be executed in my Oracle database. Since I use DBLink, Hibernate may mistakenly think that my table name (`name = "PROD_INST@HUIJK"`) contains the "@" special character, so it automatically escapes the table name. And in this case I can't prevent it from generating double quotes by setting the globally_quoted_identifiers property to false. I'm not sure if the above conjecture is correct.